# notification when a user comes online

Tags: notifications, lync

Is there a way to configure Microsoft Lync 2010 to produce a notification when a specific user comes online? Or becomes available?

For example, I want to be notified when John Doe logs into Lync or has a status of available.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Right-click on the contact and look for the item that says something like "Tag for status change alerts"

Answer (score 2):

When using Microsoft Teams, you can use the *Notify when available* context menu option, but only when right-clicking on the person in the right place: the *recent* tab in the chat sidebar.

[image: Demonstrate the "Notify when available" content-menu option in the chat sidebar]

If you haven't chatted with that person recently, then you can start a chat with them, and then right-click on their name at the top of the list. As far as I can tell, this feature does not work when right-clicking on a person in any other location within the app, even on the same page.

Comment: thank you very much!